# How does the SQL Server query optimizer choose non clustered indexes from available indexes for particular table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following non clustered indexes for `serviceregistration` table.

```
Index Name ---------------+ Column Name ----------------- + Index Type
IX_SERVICEREGISTRATION_I  |  SERREGNO                     | NONCLUSTERED   
IX_SERVICEREGISTRATION_II |  SERREGNO, SERCUSTID          | NONCLUSTERED
IX_SERVICEREGISTRATION_III|  PLACEID, JOBID, SERREGNO     | NONCLUSTERED
```

**Query 1:**

```
Select CustomerName, Place 
From dbo.ServiceRegistration
Where SERREGNO = 'JAN1234' And PLACEID = 1
```

**Query 2:**

```
Select CustomerName, Place 
From dbo.ServiceRegistration
Where SERREGNO = 'JAN1234' And SERCUSTID = 'A123'
```

**Query 3:**

```
Select CustomerName, Place 
From dbo.ServiceRegistration
Where JOBID = 5 And PLACEID = 1 And SERREGNO = 'JAN1234'
```

Whether the above created indexes will be useful for these queries or not?

Comment: Can you examine the Estimated Execution Plan (Ctrl + L in SSMS)?
Do these indexes have any INCLUDED columns?

Comment: @StevenHibble, There is no INCLUDE columns for these indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Query #1 can use `IX_SERVICEREGISTRATION_I`
- Query #2 might use `IX_SERVICEREGISTRATION_II`
- Query #3 might use index #3

Any compound index (made up from more than one column) can only ever be possibly used when you use the **n left-most columns** in your queries - that's why neither query #1 nor query #2 can make use of index #3.

But the actual use of the indices will depend on a great many more things - like how many rows out of the whole table are you selecting with this query?

None of the queries are being "covered" by and index - e.g. no query can return the values you're asking for by just looking at the index - that usually limits the usefulness of an index. If you'd be adding an `INCLUDE (CustomerName, Place)` to any of the indexes - **then** the likelihood of them being used would be significantly improved.

Comment: Please use **internationally understood** numbers - thousands, millions, billions. You need to include the column into *those indexes* that would be used for that query. So if you see that query #2 uses index #2, but always has to do a lot of *key lookups* to get the columns, it might be useful to see if including the columns into the index could help skip that extra step